# How to troubleshoot selection of audio device

Tags: audio, raspi-config

When right click on the volume icon at top right of the screen, a menu lets me select Analog or HDMI audio output.

Whatever selection I do, a green check mark appears at the selected option but there is no apparent result. Audio continues to the same output device as it was before my actions.

To be able to change the output, I run **sudo raspi-config** at the terminal, select an audio device using the menu, and then reboot. In this way, audio works fine either as Analog or as HDMI.

How can I make audio output selection through volume icon to work?